# How to use EventEmitter from child component with observable in parent (angular 2)

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a child component that emits a number:

```
this.number.emit(3);
```

In the parent component I listen to it:

```
<parent>
  <child (number)="$event"></child>
</parent>
```

In the parent class, how do I combine the EventEmitter from the child component with an observable in the parent component?

```
this.apiService.getSomeHTTPRequest()
    .combineLatest(--- ??? combine with child event emitter ??? ---)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to manually create a [Subject](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/subjects.md) in the parent component. You will need to feed this subject with data from the emitted event and use it in the `combineLatest` method. The implementation will look like that:

```
import Subject from 'rxjs/Subject'
@Component({
    // Forward events from the child component to the numberChanges subject.
    template: `<child (number)="numberChanges.next($event)"></child>`
})
class Parent {
    numberChanges = new Subject<number>()
    // Assuming you create the stream in onInit method.
    ngOnInit() {
         const stream = this.apiService.getSomeHTTPRequest()
             // Combine the numberChanges stream.
             .combineLatest(this.numberChanges)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try below,

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
  <my-child (number)="childNumber.next($event)" ></my-child>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
  childNumber: Subject<any>= new Subject<any>();

  someAPI = Observable.interval(2000);
  combined = Observable.combineLatest(this.childNumber,this.someAPI);

  constructor(){
    this.combined.subscribe(latestVals => console.log(latestVals));
  }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'my-child',
  template: `<h3>Child Component</h3>`
})
export class ChildComponent { 
  @Output() number: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  constructor(){
    Observable.interval(1000).subscribe(num => {
      this.number.emit(num);
    });
  }
}
```

Check this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vRWMre1PfebSkugiXjR7)!!

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Since that every `EventEmitter` is actually an `Observable` (`Subject` to be precise), you can subscribe to it (or combine it with other observables).

You should get the child component:

```js
@ViewChild(ChildComponent, { static: true }) child: ChildComponent;
```

And then, you can subscribe (or combine) to the `EventEmitter`s of the child:

```js
child.number.subscribe();
```

Using this technique, you do not need to listen to the event in the template:

```html
<parent>
  <child></child>
</parent>
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nh5kpv?)